# Multi boot USB With 2 Partition

Tags: boot, partitioning, usb

i am having some trouble here.i want to create a 2 partition USB so that i can multi boot Linux on 1 partition and put windows password by passer software( iseepassword to be exact) on the other partition.the problem i have is how can i boot from either partition in the bios. thanks in advance

Comment: [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) can create a persistent live drive with Ubuntu. It will create several partitions. Partition #1 will have the NTFS file system, which works well with Windows. Maybe this will solve your problem. Otherwise you can try [multiboot-usb](http://multibootusb.org/). I think the default file system can be read by Windows, so you could put the Windows password there. If you need a separate partition, you can create it afterwards with `gparted`.

Comment: I have used multi boot usb maker . First I made 2 partitions then installed the different multi boot linux isos .Then installed the I see password program to burn the program to 2nd partition(there is no option to get the iso . Also can see the site of iseepassword for more info.).The program directly tells us to burn usb.so I was successful in making usb and can boot from the multi boot partition. After that I can use plop boot manager to boot in 2nd partion but when I boot in it says boot mgr nit found. Can anyone tell me any password recovery in form of iso.

Comment: A password recovery in form of iso is beyond my knowledge.

Comment: Bro many options are available like ophcrack iso (linux) but I want a lightweight iso around 100 mb whereas ophcrack is 600 mb. If not do you know any way through which we can get the files iso from the program . And thanks for the support